# Confirm SQLbuilder query was successful in Yii

Tags: yii, query-builder

Firstly, I apologise if this is a really stupid question.

I had a question about dealing correctly with SQL statements within Yii. I'll make a small example code.

```
    public function actionCreate($id) {


    $cmd = Yii::app()->db->createCommand();
    $cmd->insert('table_1',array(
    'user_id'=> (int) $id,
    ),'id=:id', array(':id'=>$id)); 
}
```

What's the correct way to confirm this query worked? Is it try/catch blocks?

The reason I ask is that could fail if it's passed a bad parameter, but on a couple of tables I have DB constraints that could also result in a failure, so I wanted to try and make sure I handled everything properly rather than blanket handle them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From official document

> 1. Executing SQL Statements  Once a database connection is established, SQL statements can be executed using CDbCommand. One
>      creates a CDbCommand instance by calling
>      CDbConnection::createCommand() with the specified SQL statement:

```
$connection=Yii::app()->db;   // assuming you have configured a "db" connection
// If not, you may explicitly create a connection:
// $connection=new CDbConnection($dsn,$username,$password);
$command=$connection->createCommand($sql);
// if needed, the SQL statement may be updated as follows:
// $command->text=$newSQL;
```

> A SQL statement is executed via CDbCommand in one of the following two ways:

And here it is

> execute(): performs a non-query SQL statement, such as INSERT, UPDATE
>   and DELETE. If successful, it returns the number of rows that are
>   affected by the execution.

Btw, insert() is a low level method that's used internally by Active Record (AR). Why don't you simply use AR instead

By Yii gii, you automatically get model for table_1, and you can find, insert, update, delete from that. Example:

```
$model = new Table1ModelName;
$model->user_id= $id;
$model->name= $user_name;
...
$model->save();
```

There still has many workarounds and interesting things which you would like to study about
[Yii Working Active Record](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.ar)

Comment: Thanks Telvin, I'm more concerned with just dealing properly with errors such as the query failing due to some reason. I suppose I could use AR too though. The example code was just an example.

Comment: You can use try catch
try {
        Yii::app()->db->createCommand($command)->execute();
} catch (CDbException $e) {}

Comment: Thanks, that was what I was trying to confirm.